# Setting to enforce use of Excel Services rather than Excel Web App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, excel, excel-services

Our site and sub-sites are defaulting to `Excel Web App` rather than `Excel Services`.

We require `Excel Services`.

I think maybe I hit a setting somewhere at the root which has caused this change.

Where do I find the setting required to set `Excel Services` as the default ?

Comment: Sorry, but I didnot understand exactly the difference between Excel Web App and Excel Services. I know the excel web part. But thats not what you are referring to...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify per list if (under Advanced settings) if documents should default to Office Online (WAC) or the Office Client.

You cannot do it only do it for Excel files - it's always for all Office docs.